# How to create a date field once item is created?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to have a date next to the item once the item is created.

I did add `DateTimeField` in the model and added the template in my `home.html` but somehow once the item is created 'POST' nothing happens or appears.

```
class List(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_at']


def home(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ListForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            all_items = List.objects.all
            messages.success (request, 'item has been added to the list')
            return render(request, "home.html", {'all_items': all_items})
    else:
        all_items = List.objects.all
        return render(request, "home.html", {'all_items': all_items})
```

the output is nothing. date doesn't appear even though the item is successfully added.

Comment: you are missing parenthesis after `all`. It should be `List.objects.all()`.

Comment: please correct it List.objects.all to List.objects.all()

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with dates. What do you expect to "appear"?

Comment: When an item is created it simply add it to a table each row contain three columns one for the item name and second for delete button and the third should be for the date the item is created which suppose to be 31 / 8 / 2019 that's it

Comment: Please add your `ListForm` and also the HTML page code where you are showing the form

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found a few mistakes

1. It should be `List.objects.all()` instead of `List.objects.all`
2. You are trying to save a form in POST which you don't display in GET i.e the home.html page before submission

so your views code should be like:

```
def home(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ListForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            all_items = List.objects.all()
            form = ListForm()
            messages.success (request, 'item has been added to the list')
            return render(request, "home.html", {'all_items': all_items, 'form':form})
    else:
        form = ListForm()
        all_items = List.objects.all()
        return render(request, "home.html", {'all_items': all_items, 'form': form})
```

Now in the home.html

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```